# What to do to get a question more views?

Tags: discussion

Following the advice given in a previous topic, I placed a bounty on one of my questions, though it does not seem to provide additional traffic/views. So if we suppose that a bounty fails in getting a question answered, what else can a user do to attract more views? Is a second bounty worth considering?

For example: [Another chain of six circles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725852/another-chain-of-six-circles) - Has 100 bounty, no answers whatsoever, and barely any views. Another such example: [Complete integral of pde without independent variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737189/complete-integral-of-pde-without-independent-variables).

Comment: This has certainly been asked before (on a phone, not going to search at the moment). I'm honestly perplexed by why you don't just let sleeping dogs lie. I consider it a pretty significant etiquette breach to have edited your recent questions so needlessly and frequently with the clear intention of gaming the front page. I wouldn't have even noticed you'd done the same with the bountied question as well, were it not for this post.

Comment: Yes... I placed a bounty on my other question was I was informed that it was better to do so (see the first comment of my locked post).

Comment: Also, I am genuinely interested in knowing how to obtain more views, more traffic, and more answers to my questions.

Comment: Moreover: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21228/i-am-not-getting-answers-for-my-questions None of the advice present here applies.

Comment: [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3478/how-to-grab-users-attention-on-an-old-question)

Comment: About your last sentence, which seems basically as an inquiry to which extent bounty helps: [How effective are bounties?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20155/how-effective-are-bounties)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Who is your target audience?  The title "Another chain of six circles" seems intended to convince Readers that nothing important is to be solved, as in here's just another chain of six circles.

Low views are an indication that your titles don't convey anything of interest to the many different strata of community members.  So I'd start there with rethinking your strategy.

I believe there is something that interests *you* in each of these posts.  Don't try to pack the problem entirely into the title, but do be creative in using the title to pique the Readers' interest.   Even if I don't expect to be able to answer in a curious topic, I'm easily persuaded to pay attention in order to learn something new.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the feedback. I will try to design more creative titles.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that most users here don't look at the majority of questions? I am more active on cs.stackexchange, and I have the habit of looking over every new question on the front-page whenever I login.

Comment: I am here every day, and I can't imagine that any user sees the majority of Math.SE questions.  It's a firehose compared to CS.SE.

Comment: A quite long time ago, I used to be able to finish in the span of an hour looking through (and sometimes answering) questions I missed while sleeping for the last eight hours. These days, the front page is a constant avalanche that I shy away from, preferring to just look through tags of interest. If the title/content of a question looks haphazard/lazy, or it won't be fun (for me, of course) to answer, why should I bother with it?

Comment: @user340082710 I guess that [80% of the people will look at 20% of the questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle).